# php foreach loop SQL table name query

Tags: php, sql

I have this php code to do a query foreach loop going through the table name in variable $rowA but I got an "Array to string conversion" error. Does anyone know why? Can we do a query loop this way?

```
$sql = "SELECT `id`, `first_name` FROM `clients` ORDER BY `id` DESC";
$result = $DB_CON_C->query($sql);

$sql_email = "SELECT `email` FROM `clients` ORDER BY `id` DESC";
$account = $DB_CON_C->query($sql_email);

    foreach($result as $row) {
      foreach($account as $rowA) {
        $stmt = "SELECT SUM(value) AS total_amount FROM `".$rowA."`";
        $amount = $DB_CON_C->query($stmt);
        $sum = $amount->total_amount;

        $data_row .=  '<tr>'
                      . '<td>' .$row['id'].'</td>'
                      . '<td>' .$row['first_name'].'</td>'
                      . '<td>' .$sum.'</td>';
        }
      }
    }
    $data_row .=  '</tbody>'
                . '</table>';
    echo $data_row;
```

Comment: What part is causing the error? What line?

Comment: I believe this line $stmt = "SELECT SUM(value) AS total_amount "
              . "FROM `".$rowA."`";
causes the error. I just don't understand the cause of it.

Comment: just to clarify; your table column name is the email address?

Comment: @MasterJoe how should the output be like?

Comment: @Martin Yes, Martin.

Comment: @julekgwa The two lines: . '<td>' .$row['id'].'</td>'
                      '<td>' .$row['first_name'].'</td>' output the data from table "clients" and the  '<td>' .$sum.'</td>' output data from tables where the names of these tables are named after their email.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to parse a database row to a string, even though it contains only one thing.

Change the following line

```
$stmt = "SELECT SUM(value) AS total_amount "
          . "FROM `".$rowA."`";
```

to

```
$stmt = "SELECT SUM(value) AS total_amount "
          . "FROM `".$rowA['email']."`";
```

`$rowA` is a database row and contains the `email` field from the database.

Comment: This solves my problem. Thanks Dowe de Haan. However, I unexpectedly encounter another issue that I didn't have before. The two lines:
'<td>' .$row['id'].'</td>'
'<td>' .$row['first_name'].'</td>' of the first foreach loop repeat data of the first row in the table.

Comment: Hmm, strange. I would advice you to look at the answer [Martin gave](http://stackoverflow.com/a/43899728/1336174) because I know that would certainly fix your problem. You have two queries now that could be merged, which would solve it. Also, if you could edit your post with the structure of your database, we could even help you better!

Answer (score 2):

There seems to be a fundamentally odd issue with the way you are handling your data values.

Take your first query, `$result`, this will (obviously depending on the exact `$DB_CON_C` class method) output an array of values for `id` and `first_name`

Yet on the second call, `$account` using the same method you are then calling the values as if they're class variables `$amount->total_amount`.

I would suspect that one of these syntax is wrong, but without seeing your class I can't say which.

- Do you realise that your two SQL calls are both returning the whole database?
- Do you realise that you're using the data value (email address) in one table as the column name in another table? This can work, but this really isn't best practise.
- You do not need to use the concaenator `.`  for strings over new lines.

  ```
   $string = "Hello
              this string works fine";
  ```

  as white space is reduced to one character length in HTML so it doesn't matter (much).

---

**Solving your issue**:

`var_dump($account)` once the value has been populated, same with $results, do `var_dump($results)` and see what is in the value, if these are `class variables` or `arrays of data`?

---

Seeing that both your variables are calling different parts of the same table, I have rewritten your code below:

```
$sql = "SELECT `id`, `first_name`, `email` FROM `clients` ORDER BY `id` DESC";
$result = $DB_CON_C->query($sql);

/***
 * $result is assumed to be an array, within which is a set of values such as:
 * $result[0]['id']
 * $result[0]['first_name']
 * $result[0]['email']
 * $result[1]['id'], etc. 
 ***/

    foreach($result as $row) {

        $stmt = "SELECT SUM(value) AS total_amount FROM `".$row['email']."`";
        $amount = $DB_CON_C->query($stmt);
        /***
         * this is inconsistent, your data structure must be like $result as it
         * uses the same methods, therefore you will need to enter the first
         * "row" before getting the 'total_amount' value
         ***/ 
         $sum = $amount[0]['total_amount'];

        $data_row .=  '<tr>
                       <td>' .$row['id'].'</td>
                       <td>' .$row['first_name'].'</td>
                       <td>' .$sum.'</td>
                       </tr>'; //you forgot your /tr !!  
      }
      // Always clean up after foreach loops.
      unset($row);
    $data_row .=  '</tbody>
                   </table>';
    echo $data_row;
```

Comment: I've tried out your code and receive error "Cannot use object of type PDOStatement as array" on line $sum = $amount[0]['total_amount']. Thanks for the suggestion and will improve my code based on your comments. I'm new to php and javascript and only have been learning them about 3 weeks.